# $_FILES is null, $_POST is not null

Tags: php, web-applications, file-upload

When I am going to upload a file, my $_POST variable knows the file name, but the $_FILES variable is null. I've used this code before, so I'm really stumped.

Here's what I'm using for input:

```
<label for="importFile">Attach Resume:</label>
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000">
<input type="file" name="importFile" id="importFile" class="validate['required']">
```

And for processing:

```
$uploaddir = "E:/Sites/OPL/2008/assets/apps/newjobs/resumes/";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . time() . '-' . urlencode(basename($_FILES['importFile']['name']));

if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['importFile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo 'Error uploading file. Error number: ' . $_FILES['importFile']['error'];
    var_dump($_FILES['importFile']);
    echo $_POST['importFile'];
    die();
}
```

Which is giving me this result:

```
Error uploading file. Error number: NULL
Maintaining The OPL Website.doc
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you set up the form correcty ? it must contain  enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: afaik, $_FILES only works if the form is multipart encoded, so make sure your html form is so :-)

Comment: You guys are quick! I totally over looked that obvious fact. Please post as an answer so I can close off this question. Cheers

Comment: and in 1 min 3 guys had the same idea :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i'm not sure but first check if form contains

```
 enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

second check whats in $_FILES at all , i'm not sure if the $_FILES['importFile'] is right sintax ... i think it doesnt contain the name

Answer (score 3):

Does the form tag have the `enctype='multipart/form-data'` attribute?

Answer (score 2):

Have you set the `enctype` attribute of your form tag to `multipart/form-data`? It should read

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" ...
```